# How to debounce / throttle with Svelte?

Tags: javascript, svelte

So i currently have:

**App.html**

```
<div>
  <input on:input="debounce(handleInput, 300)">
</div>

<script>
  import { debounce } from 'lodash'

  export default {
    data () {
      name: ''
    },

    methods: {
      debounce,
      async handleInput (event) {
        this.set({ name: await apiCall(event.target.value).response.name })
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

And get the error `Uncaught TypeError: Expected a function at App.debounce`. This comes from Lodash so it doesn't seem like the method from Svelte is being passed through.

**Extra extra edit**

Extra context for how i'm currently achieving it:

```
oncreate () {
  const debounceFnc = this.handleInput.bind(this)

  this.refs.search.addEventListener('input', debounce(debounceFnc, 300))
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you're trying to do? You wouldn't typically have a `debounce` method on a component — instead, one of your methods would *be* debounced

Comment: @RichHarris sorry Rich my example seemed to have missed the template part i added. Added a bit more context to show what i'm trying to achieve too.

Comment: Try using `import debounce from 'lodash/debounce'`

Comment: Same error @OluwafemiSule. I further edited with extra context to show how i'm currently achieving this. I just wondered if i could do it in the template the "Svelte" way.

Comment: `debounce` is a method defined on the component so it should be used as `this.debounce(debounceFnc, 300)`

Comment: I've tried both `debounce` and `this.debounce`. I registered it on the component to see if it would with on this `on:input` as i couldn't use it straight up without declaring in in `methods: {}` i also tried `helpers: {}` and that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It's the method itself that should be debounced — so rather than calling `debounce` on each input event, set `handleInput` up to be a debounced method:

#### Svelte v3 version

```html
<input on:input={handleInput}>

<script>
  import debounce from 'lodash/debounce'

  let name = '';
    
  const handleInput = debounce(e => {
    name = e.target.value;
  }, 300)
</script>
```

[REPL example here.](https://svelte.dev/repl/52e9b3d7a5654021b58597fe807d53d8?version=3.20.1)

#### Older Svelte version

```html
<div>
  <input on:input="handleInput(event)">
</div>

<script>
  import { debounce } from 'lodash'

  export default {
    data () {
      return { name: '' };
    },

    methods: {
      handleInput: debounce (async function (event) {
        this.set({ name: await apiCall(event.target.value).response.name })
      }, 300)
    }
  }
</script>
```

[Simplified REPL example here.](https://svelte.technology/repl?version=1.38.0&gist=f2a35e769e1a615f43f0aee679097fa2)

Comment: Had no idea you could import from lodash in the REPL. Thanks, Rich!

Comment: Is there an updated example of how to do this in Svelte 3? I'm struggling since the syntax has changed so drastically

Comment: @TheHanna i assume you've worked it out but I've updated the answer.  cheers Rich for all the work you've done.

Comment: Typing seems like a pain. Cannot assign type 'Function' to type 'UIEventHandler'. Any fixes? (Using JSDoc for typing)

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is valid for Svelte v1. For v3, you can achieve the same with this code:

```
<input placeholder='edit me' bind:this={input}>
<p>name: {name}</p>

<script>
  import { onMount } from "svelte"
    import { debounce } from 'lodash-es'
    var name="", input;
    onMount(()=>{
        input.addEventListener('input', debounce((e)=>{name=e.target.value}, 250))
    })
</script>
```

Comment: you should not have to use a ref for this use the on:input directive :)